# Use i18next with coreUI react sidebar

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I'm using coreUI react free admin dashboard template https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/
n I'm using i18next to translate texts and set website direction (RTL / LRT) https://react.i18next.com/

Problem is I'm not sure how to use i18next with the contents of sidebar of the template, as it's simply a list / an array of objects as listed below,

```
const menuList =  [
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    to: '/dashboard',
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTachometerAlt} className="c-sidebar-nav-icon"/>,
  },
...
]
```

and as it's not build as a react component, I can't do something like

```
name: {t('Dashboard')},
```

list is called inside the sidebar as below...

```
<CSidebarNav>
  <CCreateElement
    items={menuList }
    components={{
      CSidebarNavDivider,
      CSidebarNavDropdown,
      CSidebarNavItem,
      CSidebarNavTitle
    }}
  />
</CSidebarNav>
```

so I guess a need away to manipulate the list before sending it as "items" to be rendered and showed

Answer (score 2):

You can use  **Translation (render prop)** https://react.i18next.com/latest/translation-render-prop

```
import { Translation } from 'react-i18next';
const menuList =  [
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: <Translation>{(t) => <>{t('Dashboard')}</>}</Translation>,
    to: '/dashboard',
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTachometerAlt} className="c-sidebar-nav-icon"/>,
  },
...
]
```